# Delete last row from the table if total number for rows are more than 3

Tags: mysql, sql

Delete last row from the table only if total number for rows are more than 3.

How do I determine if total number for records are more than 3 and only then delete the last or oldest row?

```
DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_post_ID` = 23 ORDER BY `comment_ID` LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi there. In order to us to help you out, please tag the database you're on and get us please some test data to play with

Answer (score 1):

We can try doing a join delete here, with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
DELETE wp1
FROM wp_comments wp1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT comment_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY comment_ID DESC) rn
    FROM wp_comments
) wp2
    ON wp2.comment_ID = wp1.comment_ID
WHERE
    wp2.rn > 3;
```

The strategy here is to assign a row number to every record in the table, using `comment_ID` as the ordering.  The row number count starts at 1 for the *oldest* entry, and increases from there.  We delete any records besides the most recent 3.

Note that the above approach requires MySQL 8+, and if you're using an earlier version of MySQL, now might be a good time to upgrade.